# Server in Go not listening on tun0

Tags: linux, go, tun

I'm running a simple, standard Go TCP server and I want to bind it to my tun0 interface.

The server is:

```
func main() {
    conn, err := net.Listen("tcp", "10.1.0.21:4444")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    defer conn.Close()

    fmt.Println("Running on 10.1.0.21:4444")
    c, err := conn.Accept()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }

    for {
        data, err := bufio.NewReader(c).ReadString('\n')
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
            return
        }

        fmt.Print("Got ", data)
        myTime := "Hello"
        c.Write([]byte(myTime))
    }
}
```

As root, to create tun0, I run:

```
ip tuntap add mode tun dev tun0
ip addr add 10.1.0.20/24 dev tun0
ip link set dev tun0 up
```

When listening on `10.1.0.21`, the server can't run:

> listen tcp 10.1.0.21:4444: bind: cannot assign requested address

It can listen on `10.1.0.20`, but Wireshark (as root) does not intercept any packet on tun0, while I'm using `netcat` (`nc`) to send packets to it and the server responds successfully.

Why can't it bind to `10.1.0.21`? Why can't Wireshark intercept any traffic when it listens on `10.1.0.20`?

Comment: have you checked on the permissions of the device file?

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg how do I check them? I'm running the program as root, but I will still double check. I'm using this to debug [my other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60681928/tcp-handshake-never-complete-with-raw-sockets-and-tun0), both on Ubuntu

Comment: You assigned .21 not .20. You have to run `ip addr add 10.1.0.21/24 dev tun0` to make it available.

Comment: @Peter "You assigned .21 not .20. You have to run ip addr add 10.1.0.21/24 dev tun0 to make it available." isn't `10.1.0.21/24` the same as `10.1.0.20/24`?

Comment: Not at all. One assigns .20 in the subnet and one assigns .21 in the same subnet. It does *not* assign all addresses in the subnet if that's what you expected. It's just short for `addr add 10.1.0.20 netmask 255.255.255.0` (or something like that; I forget the exact command).

Comment: @Peter Got it, thanks. Do you have any idea on why Wireshark doesn't intercept traffic when I use `10.1.0.20`?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to select the loopback interface to capture that traffic, as the traffic is local. See also: https://www.naturalborncoder.com/virtualization/2014/10/17/understanding-tun-tap-interfaces/

And your other question regarding binding to `10.1.0.21` has been answered in the comments above.